# How to get all pages from a REST API with BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just started playing around with BackboneJS not too long ago and I've ran into an issue.

I am making this call with with my collection and when fetching it, my Javascript only gets the first page of 10 results.

```
 "http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json";
```

Of course, this is normal because when you open the URL you will see that the API itself only shows the 10 first results in JSON, along with a link to the next page of 10 results.

This is how I am fetching the data:

```
 movies.fetch({data: {page:1}, success: this.renderdata.bind(this)});
```

Obviously I could just duplicate that line of code and count how many pages there are, but how could I programmatically figure out how many pages there are and make sure Backbone fetches the data from all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library such as [Backbone Paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) to manage paged APIs. It will use the `count` value, and any `next` or `previous` links, in the JSON response to allow you to move back and forth through those pages.